# In Magento1, how do you establish where the translations csv file is to be uploaded?

Tags: magento-1, localisation, translate

I have my translate.csv file ready to upload into a Magento setup. So we are changing words from Magento default like Tax to be VAT instead. I understand different setups will have this file uploaded in different locations? I thought it would be app/design/frontend/theme/default/locale/en_US but that's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

To do this why not just enable the inline translator? instructions on this can be found here https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-use-translate-inline-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer for everyone, but after a while I established I was editing the wrong translations file! It's a UK store we were working on, so it was in the en_GB folder not en_US..... but it was indeed the translate.csv file that is to be edited.